# Swagger declaration schema = @Schema(implementation = Map.class) represents Schema as String in swagger-ui

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, springdoc, springdoc-ui

I am trying to create `springdoc` swagger documentation, and I would like to represent a request body having data type `Map<String, Object>` in a better readable way for clients. But when I declare `@io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.parameters.RequestBody(content = @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = Map.class)` the Schema is coming as `String`(attached the screenshot below)

[image]

**Method declaration**

```
        @Operation(security = {@SecurityRequirement(name = "bearer-key")}, summary = "Create Data", operationId = "createData", description = "Create createData for the **`type`**. ")
    @ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "201", description = "Data created", content = @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = Map.class),
                    examples = {@ExampleObject(value = "{\n" +
                            "    \"id\": \"927d810c-3ac5-4584-ba58-7c11befabf54\",\n" +
                            "}")})),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "400", description = "BAD Request")})
    @PostMapping(value = "/data/type", produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.parameters.RequestBody(content = @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = Map.class),
            examples = {@ExampleObject(value = "{\n" +
                    "            \"label\":\"tourism\",\n" +
                    "            \"location\":\"France\"\n" +
                    "         }")}))
    ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> createData(@Parameter(name = "type", required = true) @PathVariable("type") String type, @Parameter(name = "request payload") @Valid @RequestBody Map<String, Object> body);
```

Though the Spring boot automatically infers the type based on the method signature, it is not clear for the data type `Map`. For instance, by default, the type Map<String, Object> will be inferred as below
[image]

But I would like to show the Schema in a more understandable way for the client who refers to my API. I could see there is a closed ticket without a proper solution in [Github](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/3439). As per my requirement, the request body should be a type agnostic and dynamic key-value pairs, so there is no other way apart from receiving the request as `Map<String, Object>`. has anyone implemented a better way with type `Map` rather than creating a custom request/response model?

Comment: Saw the issue [here](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/743)?

Comment: yeah all injectable parameter types supported by Spring MVC are excluded and ignored by the swagger, the complete list is available in the [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.1.x/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-arguments), the suggested solution is not most elegant and may not suit for all requirement mainly if your reponse type is `Map<String, Object>` then suggested approach will not suit

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sharing my working approach for the issue, I have done a workaround for the `@io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.parameters.RequestBody(content = @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = Map.class)` the Schema is coming as String issue.

I have declared a custom schema called Map in the OpenAPI bean declaration as below

```
new OpenAPI()
                .components(new Components()
                        .addSchemas("Map", new Schema<Map<String, Object>>().addProperties("< * >", new ObjectSchema())
                        ))
                    .....
                    .....
```

and used the above schema in the Schema declaration as below

```
 @io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.parameters.RequestBody(
            content = @Content(mediaType = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, 
                 schema = @Schema(ref = "#/components/schemas/Map"))
```

The above approach can be used in the place of `ApiResponse` also as below

```
 @io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.responses.ApiResponse(responseCode = "200",
            content = @Content(mediaType = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, 
                 schema = @Schema(ref = "#/components/schemas/Map"))
```

**Note**: If we use the above custom schema approach, we don't need to alter or ignore any of the types which `SpringDoc` is using internally.

Comment: thanks! To generate an ApiClient by openapi-generator-maven-plugin I had to set skipValidateSpec=true because of the schema Map at install

Answer (score 8):

I have one API endpoint, the request body expects a HashMap. There is not much information on how to fix the "Example value" issue.  [Prasanth's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65102336/15323483) lead me to the right place. I'm posting my solution for completeness but all credit goes to him. (PS: I tried to upvote his answer but I don't have enough "points")

The configurations side:

```java
@Configuration
@OpenAPIDefinition
public class DocsConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public OpenAPI customOpenAPI() {
        Schema newUserSchema = new Schema<Map<String, Object>>()
                .addProperties("name",new StringSchema().example("John123"))
                .addProperties("password",new StringSchema().example("P4SSW0RD"))
                .addProperties("image",new StringSchema().example("https://robohash.org/John123.png"));

        return new OpenAPI()
                //.servers(servers)
                .info(new Info()
                        .title("Your app title")
                        .description("App description")
                        .version("1.0")
                        .license(new License().name("GNU/GPL").url("https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html"))
                )
                .components(new Components()
                        .addSchemas("NewUserBody" , newUserSchema)
                );
    }
}
```

The controller side:

```java
    @io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.parameters.RequestBody(
            content = @Content(mediaType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
                    schema = @Schema(ref = "#/components/schemas/NewUserBody")))
    @PostMapping("/v1/users")
    public Response<User> upsertUser(@RequestBody HashMap<String,Object> user) {
         //Your code here
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your compliment, your solution perfectly fits if there are one or two APIs with a Map input body, but if there are 10 to 15 API that expects the inputs, it will be a cumbersome process to construct the 15 schemas and configure.

Answer (score 2):

Id like to update [rodiri's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66550936/1435948) for my situation. I had to combine the answer by rodiri and this [answer by Ondřej Černobila](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64158579/1435948) to the SO question [SpringDoc - How to Add schemas programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61729201/springdoc-how-to-add-schemas-programmatically). I am using java 11, spring-boot-starter-parent 2.5.6, and springdoc-openapi-ui 1.5.12 which I believe is using swagger 3.52.5

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springdoc/springdoc-openapi-ui -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.12</version>
</dependency>
```

My config

```java
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.OpenAPIDefinition;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.media.ObjectSchema;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.media.StringSchema;
import org.springdoc.core.customizers.OpenApiCustomiser;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@OpenAPIDefinition
public class DocsConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public OpenApiCustomiser openApiCustomiser() {
    return openApi -> {
      var NewUserBodySchema = new ObjectSchema()
          .name("NewUserBody")
          .title("NewUserBody")
          .description("Object description")
          .addProperties("name", new StringSchema().example("John123"))
          .addProperties("password", new StringSchema().example("P4SSW0RD"))
          .addProperties("image", new StringSchema().example("https://robohash.org/John123.png"));

      var schemas = openApi.getComponents().getSchemas();
      schemas.put(NewUserBodySchema.getName(), NewUserBodySchema);
    };
  }

}
```

For my endpoint I am using a get that returns a Map so its different from the accepted answer.

```java
@GetMapping(value = "/{userId}")
@Operation(
    summary = "Get Something",
    description = "Some desciption",
    responses = {
        @ApiResponse(
            responseCode = "200",
            description = "The Map Response",
            content = {
                @Content(
                    mediaType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
                    schema = @Schema(ref = "#/components/schemas/NewUserBody")
                )
            })
    }
)
public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> getMap(@PathVariable String userId)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the default behaviour of the springdoc-openapi library in order to ignore other injectable parameters supported by Spring MVC.

- https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.x/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-arguments

If you want to change this behaviour, you can just exlcude it as follow:

```
    SpringDocUtils.getConfig().removeRequestWrapperToIgnore(Map.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem myself today. As it turns out, this is actually a design problem with Swagger (@see [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41107376/10446433)).

Nonetheless, I tried my hand at it too, using the approaches from here and the other thread.

Here is my OpenAPI with one custom schema for a `Map<Integer,String>`:

```
@Configuration
@OpenAPIDefinition(
        info = @io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.info.Info(
                title = "ACME Inc. REST API",
                version = "1.0",
                description = "This is an overview of all REST endpoints of this application",
                contact = @io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.info.Contact(name = "John Doe", url = "https://acme-inc.com/", email = "john.doe@acme-inc.com")
        )
)
public class OpenAPIConfig {
        public static final String ERROR_CODE_MAPPER = "ErrorCode-Mapper";

        @Bean
        public OpenApiCustomiser openApiCustomiser() {
                return openApi -> {
                        Components components = openApi.getComponents();
                        for(Schema<?> schema: buildCustomSchemas()) {
                                components.addSchemas(schema.getName(), schema);
                        }
                };
        }

        private static List<Schema<?>> buildCustomSchemas() {
                ArrayList<Schema<?>> result = new ArrayList<>();

                Schema<?> integerStringMap = new Schema<Map<Integer, String>>()
                        .name(ERROR_CODE_MAPPER)
                        .type("object")
                        .addProperty("error code", new StringSchema().example("Error message belonging to the error code")).example(getErrorCodeExample());
                result.add(integerStringMap);
                // Build more custom schemas...

                return result;
        }

        private static Map<Integer, String> getErrorCodeExample() {
                Map<Integer, String> example = new HashMap<>();
                example.put(666, "Oh no..., the devil himself  showed up and stopped your request");
                return example;
        }
}
```

(**NOTE:** Look up your swagger source code `io.swagger.v3.oas.models.media` for useful utility classes like `StringSchema`. You don't have write everything from scratch.)

And this is my REST endpoint:

```
@Operation(summary = "This endpoint returns a list of system error codes, that can occur during processing requests.")
@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(
                responseCode = "200",
                description = "Map of all system error codes mapping to their messages",
                content = {@Content(mediaType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, schema = @Schema(ref = "#/components/schemas/"+ ERROR_CODE_MAPPER))}
        )
})
@GetMapping("/error-codes")
public Map<Integer, String> listErrorCodes() {
    // return your map here...
}
```

This produces something like this:

[image]

It is important to know that in a JSON object the key is always of type `string`. So the type does not have to be written explicitly. With that in mind, this is the schema:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. I created a HashMap extension class:

   ```
    @Schema(description = "Response-Object Map<String, EcoBalance).")
    public class EcoMap extends HashMap<String, EcoBalance> {
      @JsonIgnore
      @Override
      public boolean isEmpty() {
        return super.isEmpty();
      }
    }
   ```
2. use it as response object

   ```
    @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", content = @Content(mediaType = .., schema = @Schema(implementation = EcoMap.class)), headers = ..
   ```
3. be aware the OpenAPI 3 generator does not generate such a client-model, but is properly referenced in openapi.yml (and even validates).