# How to use @RequestParam Map<String,String> properly in Swagger UI?

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, springfox

I'm trying to use springfox-swagger-ui for this request:

```
@GetMapping(value = "")
public String Hello( @RequestParam Map<String, String> params )
```

When I open Swagger UI and try the request, it shows the parameters like this:

[image: pic.2]

and the request query string will be like:

```
?params%5BadditionalProp1%5D=string&params%5BadditionalProp2%5D=string&params%5BadditionalProp3%5D=string
```

I don't want the word "params" to be included in the query string, I want the parameters be like `?additionalProp1=string ....`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to find a solution to this by combining @Helen's response and the accepted response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65010272/swagger-declaration-schema-schemaimplementation-map-class-represents-sche). Basically my situation is that the OpenAPI UI was also showing me the following default JSON:

```json
{
    "additionalProps1": "string",
    "additionalProps2": "string",
    "additionalProps3": "string"
}
```

but what I needed instead was a default like:

```json
{
  "sourceAccountId": "1",
  "targetAccountId": "2"
}
```

So I added the following new schema called `ParameterMap` to my `OpenApi` bean:

```java
return new OpenAPI()
    .
    .
    .
    .components(
            new Components()
                .
                .
                .
                .addSchemas("ParameterMap", new Schema<Map<String, String>>().addProperty("sourceAccountId", 
                                new StringSchema().example("1")).addProperty("targetAccountId", new StringSchema().example("2")))
```

and referred to it as follows from my `@Parameter` annotation (note the `ref` attribute of the `@Schema` annotation):

```java
@GetMapping("/transactions")
public ResponseEntity<CollectionModel<EntityModel<TransactionDto>>> getAllTransactions(
       @Parameter(name = "params",
                  in = ParameterIn.QUERY,
                  required = true,
                  schema = @Schema(type = "object", additionalProperties = Schema.AdditionalPropertiesValue.TRUE, 
                      ref = "#/components/schemas/ParameterMap"),
                  style = ParameterStyle.FORM,
                  explode = Explode.TRUE)
          @RequestParam Map<String, String> params){
.
.
.
}
```

Now the OpenAPI UI renders everything as I want it and the `curl` call betrays that `params` is not part of the query string:

[image: The desired OpenAPI3 UI and query string.]

Hope this helps.

Comment: are you using springfox? version?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following `@Parameter` annotation to your parameter (line breaks added for readability). The `style` and `explode` attributes specify that the map parameter should be serialized as `?key1=value1&key2=value2&...` without including the parameter name ("params").

```java
@GetMapping(value = "")
public String Hello(
  @Parameter(name = "params",
             in = ParameterIn.QUERY,
             required = true,
             schema = @Schema(type = "object", additionalProperties = true),
             style = ParameterStyle.FORM,
             explode = Explode.TRUE)
  @RequestParam Map<String, String> params
)
```

Comment: but I have an additional question. 
How can I set the example value as a Json form ? not set the schema.

Comment: Do you mean how to override the default displayed example `{"additionalProp1": "string", ...}` with a custom example?

Comment: @Helen I can't tell if that was troy's question, but it is definitely mine; how might I be able to do this? :)

Comment: I was actually able to find a solution to this (if indeed it was what @troy wanted), based on another SO post, see my separate answer.