# [OpenApi v3]: Embedded @ArraySchema does not appear in example value

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, swagger-ui, openapi, springdoc-openapi-ui

I have the following simple DTO:

```java
public class AccountDto {
  @Schema(example = "1", hidden = true)
  private Long id;
  @Schema(example = "100")
  @NonNull private BigDecimal balance;
  @Schema(example = "USD")
  @NonNull private Currency currency;
}
```

And the following endpoint which returns a `ResponseEntity` with a body of `org.springframework.hateoas.CollectionModel` over `org.springframework.hateoas.EntityModel`s of `AccountDto`s:

```java
@GetMapping("/account")
  public ResponseEntity<CollectionModel<EntityModel<AccountDto>>> getAllAccounts() {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(
        accountModelAssembler.toCollectionModel(accountService.getAllAccounts()));
  }
```

An example of what my endpoint returns is:

```json
{
  "_embedded": {
    "accountDtoList": [
      {
        "id": 7,
        "balance": 100,
        "currency": "AFN",
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/bankapi/account/7"
          },
          "all_accounts": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/bankapi/account"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 8,
        "balance": 120,
        "currency": "USD",
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/bankapi/account/8"
          },
          "all_accounts": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/bankapi/account"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 9,
        "balance": 100,
        "currency": "USD",
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/bankapi/account/9"
          },
          "all_accounts": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/bankapi/account"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/bankapi/account"
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to emulate this pattern in the example response body of my OpenAPI specification. Influenced by the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65010272/swagger-declaration-schema-schemaimplementation-map-class-represents-sche), I have this above my endpoint's definition in `getAllAccounts()` (notice the `ref` attribute of the `@Schema` annotation):

```java
 @Operation(summary = "Get all accounts")
  @ApiResponses(value = {
          @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "All accounts successfully retrieved",
                  content = {
                      @Content(mediaType = "application/json",
                          schema = @Schema(ref = "#/components/schemas/CollectionModelAccountDto")) }),
          @ApiResponse(responseCode = "401", description = "Unauthenticated user",
                  content = @Content) })
```

and in the declaration of my `@OpenAPI` bean I attempt to define the schema `CollectionModelAccountDto` as follows:

```java
 return new OpenAPI()
        .components(
            new Components()
                .addSchemas(
                    "CollectionModelAccountDto",
                    new Schema<CollectionModel<EntityModel<AccountDto>>>()
                        .addProperty(
                            "_embedded",
                            new ObjectSchema()
                                .addProperty(
                                    "accountDtoList",
                                    new ArraySchema().addProperty("foo", new ObjectSchema())))
                        .addProperty("_links", new JsonSchema()))
        .
        .
        .
```

My problem is that when I use the embedded `ArraySchema` as the value of the property `"accountDtoList"` that I have in the embedded `ObjectSchema`, OpenAPI does not seem to render the `ObjectSchema` at all:

[image: The embedded ArraySchema is not rendered.]

If, however, I change the type of the embedded `Schema` from `ArraySchema` to `ObjectSchema` (or even `JsonSchema`), then I get the entire object rendered at full depth:

[image: The embedded ObjectSchema is rendered.]

Of course this is *not* what I want, since the value associated with `"accountDtoList"` needs to be a list, not an object, but I don't quite understand why the rendering of the embedded `ArraySchema` does not work. Appreciate any advice.