# How to define map API Responses @Schema with quarkus

Tags: quarkus

I have API controller with Map as a presence object

Here is my example code

```
  @GET
  @Path("/all")
  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  @APIResponses(
      value = {
          @APIResponse(
              responseCode = "200",
              description = "OK",
              content = @Content(mediaType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,
                  schema = @Schema(type = SchemaType.OBJECT, implementation = PojoDto.class))
          ),
          @APIResponse(
              responseCode = "400",
              description = "Bad Request",
              content = @Content(mediaType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,
                  schema = @Schema(implementation = RestApiError.class))
          ),
          @APIResponse(
              responseCode = "401",
              description = "Unauthorized"
          ),
          @APIResponse(
              responseCode = "403",
              description = "Forbidden"
          ),
          @APIResponse(
              responseCode = "404",
              description = "Not Found",
              content = @Content(mediaType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,
                  schema = @Schema(implementation = RestApiError.class))
          )
      }
  )
public Map<String, PojoDto> getAll() {
        return service.getAll();
}
```

How properly define `@Schema`

Comment: It's a design issue with Swagger. You can find more information in these answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65010272/swagger-declaration-schema-schemaimplementation-map-class-represents-sche

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how to do it

```
  @GET
  @Path("/all")
  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  @APIResponses(
      value = {
          @APIResponse(
              responseCode = "200",
              description = "OK",
              content = @Content(mediaType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,
                  schema = @Schema(type = SchemaType.OBJECT properties = {
                  @SchemaProperty(name = "mapKeyVal", implementation = PojoDto.class)
              }))
          ),
          @APIResponse(
              responseCode = "400",
              description = "Bad Request",
              content = @Content(mediaType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,
                  schema = @Schema(implementation = RestApiError.class))
          ),
          @APIResponse(
              responseCode = "401",
              description = "Unauthorized"
          ),
          @APIResponse(
              responseCode = "403",
              description = "Forbidden"
          ),
          @APIResponse(
              responseCode = "404",
              description = "Not Found",
              content = @Content(mediaType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,
                  schema = @Schema(implementation = RestApiError.class))
          )
      }
  )
public Map<String, PojoDto> getAll() {
        return service.getAll();
}
```